# Constructor not found in linking phase

Tags: c++, linker

Maybe I am tired (which I am indeed), but I cannot really see why my code won't link.

Environment:

- a static library
- an executable

The library compiles & links just fine, and contains the following files:

**soStrings.h**

```
#ifndef __soStrings__
#define __soStrings__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Strings storage
class soStrings
{
public:
    soStrings();

    void insert(const std::string &s);

private:

    // Whatever
};

#endif /* defined(__soStrings__) */
```

**soStrings.cpp**

```
#include "soStrings.h"

// Constructor
soStrings::soStrings()
{
    // NOP
}

// Inserts a new string
void soStrings::insert(const std::string &s)
{
    // Something
}
```

The puzzling error is shown when linking the executable:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "soStrings::soStrings()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why am I getting this? The library links fine, the only other class (a templated one) works fine, and the `.a` file contains both `.o` files. The above code is *actually the real class* copied and pasted.

The class is actually so stupid right now that I am failing to see what I'm doing wrong.

+10 internets to those who can help me :)

Cheers!

**EDIT** Adding build phases.

```
Write auxiliary files

/bin/mkdir -p [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64
write-file [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dummyprojo.LinkFileList

CompileC DerivedData/dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/soStringsBLAH.o dummyprojo/soStringsBLAH.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/dummyproj/dummyproj
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=[...]ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/dummyprojo-generated-files.hmap -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/dummyprojo-own-target-headers.hmap -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/dummyprojo-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/dummyprojo-project-headers.hmap -iquote/usr/local/include -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/DerivedSources -F[...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/soStringsBLAH.d --serialize-diagnostics [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/soStringsBLAH.dia -c /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/dummyproj/dummyproj/dummyprojo/soStringsBLAH.cpp -o [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/soStringsBLAH.o

CompileC DerivedData/dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/soParser.o soParser.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/dummyproj/dummyproj
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=[...]ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/dummyprojo-generated-files.hmap -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/dummyprojo-own-target-headers.hmap -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/dummyprojo-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/dummyprojo-project-headers.hmap -iquote/usr/local/include -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/DerivedSources -F[...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/soParser.d --serialize-diagnostics [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/soParser.dia -c /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/dummyproj/dummyproj/soParser.cpp -o [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/soParser.o

Libtool DerivedData/dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug/libdummyprojo.a normal x86_64
    cd /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/dummyproj/dummyproj
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L[...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -filelist [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyprojo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dummyprojo.LinkFileList -o [...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug/libdummyprojo.a

Write auxiliary files

/bin/mkdir -p [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64
write-file [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dummyproj.LinkFileList
write-file [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/dummyproj.hmap
write-file [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/dummyproj-own-target-headers.hmap
write-file [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/dummyproj-all-target-headers.hmap
write-file [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/dummyproj-project-headers.hmap
write-file [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/dummyproj-generated-files.hmap

CompileC DerivedData/dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o dummyproj/main.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/dummyproj/dummyproj
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=[...]ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/dummyproj-generated-files.hmap -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/dummyproj-own-target-headers.hmap -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/dummyproj-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/dummyproj-project-headers.hmap -iquote/usr/local/include -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I[...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/DerivedSources -F[...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d --serialize-diagnostics [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia -c /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/dummyproj/dummyproj/dummyproj/main.cpp -o [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o

Ld DerivedData/dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug/dummyproj normal x86_64
    cd /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/dummyproj/dummyproj
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L[...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -F[...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug -filelist [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dummyproj.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker [...]dummyproj/Build/Intermediates/dummyproj.build/Debug/dummyproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/dummyproj_dependency_info.dat -o [...]dummyproj/Build/Products/Debug/dummyproj

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "soStringsAYE::soStringsAYE()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**nm** on the library.

```
% nm ./Products/Debug/libdummyproj.a

./Products/Debug/libdummyproj.a(soStringsBLAH.o):
000000000003ab90 s EH_frame0
000000000003ac28 s EH_frame1
000000000003ab44 s GCC_except_table20
000000000003ab70 s GCC_except_table27
000000000003aa84 s GCC_except_table3
000000000003aab0 s GCC_except_table4
000000000003aadc s GCC_except_table5
000000000003ab04 s GCC_except_table8
000000000003ab2c s GCC_except_table9
                 U __Unwind_Resume
0000000000000400 T __ZN12soStringsAYE6insertERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE
000000000003ac00 S __ZN12soStringsAYE6insertERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE.eh
0000000000000000 T __ZN12soStringsAYEC1Ev
000000000003aba8 S __ZN12soStringsAYEC1Ev.eh
0000000000000020 T __ZN12soStringsAYEC2Ev
000000000003abd0 S __ZN12soStringsAYEC2Ev.eh
                 U __ZNKSt3__120__vector_base_commonILb1EE20__throw_length_errorEv
0000000000037f10 S __ZNKSt3__14hashINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEEclERKS6_
000000000003ad58 S __ZNKSt3__14hashINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEEclERKS6_.eh
0000000000039df0 S __ZNKSt3__16vectorINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEE8max_sizeEv
000000000003afe8 S __ZNKSt3__16vectorINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEE8max_sizeEv.eh
0000000000035b50 S __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS7_S8_NS_4hashIS7_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS7_S8_NS_8equal_toIS7_EELb1EEENS5_IS8_EEE20__node_insert_uniqueEPNS_11__hash_nodeIS8_PvEE
000000000003aca8 S __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS7_S8_NS_4hashIS7_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS7_S8_NS_8equal_toIS7_EELb1EEENS5_IS8_EEE20__node_insert_uniqueEPNS_11__hash_nodeIS8_PvEE.eh
000000000003a0f0 S __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS7_S8_NS_4hashIS7_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS7_S8_NS_8equal_toIS7_EELb1EEENS5_IS8_EEE4findIS7_EENS_15__hash_iteratorIPNS_11__hash_nodeIS8_PvEEEERKT_
000000000003b038 S __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS7_S8_NS_4hashIS7_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS7_S8_NS_8equal_toIS7_EELb1EEENS5_IS8_EEE4findIS7_EENS_15__hash_iteratorIPNS_11__hash_nodeIS8_PvEEEERKT_.eh
0000000000036ca0 S __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS7_S8_NS_4hashIS7_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS7_S8_NS_8equal_toIS7_EELb1EEENS5_IS8_EEE6rehashEm
000000000003ad00 S __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS7_S8_NS_4hashIS7_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS7_S8_NS_8equal_toIS7_EELb1EEENS5_IS8_EEE6rehashEm.eh
0000000000037150 S __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS7_S8_NS_4hashIS7_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS7_S8_NS_8equal_toIS7_EELb1EEENS5_IS8_EEE8__rehashEm
000000000003ad28 S __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS7_S8_NS_4hashIS7_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS7_S8_NS_8equal_toIS7_EELb1EEENS5_IS8_EEE8__rehashEm.eh
                 U __ZNSt3__112__next_primeEm
                 U __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1ERKS5_
                 U __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED1Ev
0000000000034fd0 S __ZNSt3__113unordered_mapINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmNS_4hashIS6_EENS_8equal_toIS6_EENS4_INS_4pairIKS6_mEEEEE25__construct_node_with_keyERSC_
000000000003ac78 S __ZNSt3__113unordered_mapINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmNS_4hashIS6_EENS_8equal_toIS6_EENS4_INS_4pairIKS6_mEEEEE25__construct_node_with_keyERSC_.eh
00000000000346f0 S __ZNSt3__113unordered_mapINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmNS_4hashIS6_EENS_8equal_toIS6_EENS4_INS_4pairIKS6_mEEEEEixERSC_
000000000003ac48 S __ZNSt3__113unordered_mapINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEmNS_4hashIS6_EENS_8equal_toIS6_EENS4_INS_4pairIKS6_mEEEEEixERSC_.eh
0000000000039700 S __ZNSt3__114__split_bufferINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS4_IS6_EEEC1EmmS8_
000000000003af48 S __ZNSt3__114__split_bufferINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS4_IS6_EEEC1EmmS8_.eh
0000000000039f00 S __ZNSt3__114__split_bufferINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS4_IS6_EEEC2EmmS8_
000000000003b010 S __ZNSt3__114__split_bufferINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS4_IS6_EEEC2EmmS8_.eh
0000000000039bb0 S __ZNSt3__114__split_bufferINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS4_IS6_EEED1Ev
000000000003af98 S __ZNSt3__114__split_bufferINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS4_IS6_EEED1Ev.eh
0000000000039bd0 S __ZNSt3__114__split_bufferINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS4_IS6_EEED2Ev
000000000003afc0 S __ZNSt3__114__split_bufferINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS4_IS6_EEED2Ev.eh
0000000000039180 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE11__shift_mixEm
000000000003aea0 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE11__shift_mixEm.eh
0000000000038fe0 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE13__hash_len_16Emm
000000000003ae28 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE13__hash_len_16Emm.eh
00000000000388c0 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE18__hash_len_0_to_16EPKcm
000000000003adb0 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE18__hash_len_0_to_16EPKcm.eh
0000000000038aa0 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE19__hash_len_17_to_32EPKcm
000000000003add8 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE19__hash_len_17_to_32EPKcm.eh
0000000000038bf0 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE19__hash_len_33_to_64EPKcm
000000000003ae00 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE19__hash_len_33_to_64EPKcm.eh
00000000000392e0 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE22__rotate_by_at_least_1Emi
000000000003aef0 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE22__rotate_by_at_least_1Emi.eh
0000000000039070 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE29__weak_hash_len_32_with_seedsEPKcmm
000000000003ae50 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE29__weak_hash_len_32_with_seedsEPKcmm.eh
00000000000391a0 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE29__weak_hash_len_32_with_seedsEmmmmmm
000000000003aec8 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE29__weak_hash_len_32_with_seedsEmmmmmm.eh
0000000000039120 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE8__rotateEmi
000000000003ae78 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EE8__rotateEmi.eh
0000000000038260 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EEclEPKvm
000000000003ad88 S __ZNSt3__121__murmur2_or_cityhashImLm64EEclEPKvm.eh
0000000000039320 S __ZNSt3__16vectorINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKS6_EEvOT_
000000000003af18 S __ZNSt3__16vectorINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKS6_EEvOT_.eh
0000000000039740 S __ZNSt3__16vectorINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEE26__swap_out_circular_bufferERNS_14__split_bufferIS6_RS7_EE
000000000003af70 S __ZNSt3__16vectorINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEE26__swap_out_circular_bufferERNS_14__split_bufferIS6_RS7_EE.eh
                 U __ZSt9terminatev
                 U __ZdlPv
                 U __Znwm
0000000000036c80 S ___clang_call_terminate
000000000003acd8 S ___clang_call_terminate.eh
                 U ___cxa_begin_catch
                 U ___gxx_personality_v0
                 U _ceilf
                 U _memcmp

./Products/Debug/libdummyproj.a(soParser.o):
000000000000fae0 s EH_frame0
000000000000fdf0 s EH_frame1
000000000000fa1c s GCC_except_table19
000000000000faa4 s GCC_except_table21
000000000000fad0 s L_.str
000000000000fad3 s L_.str9
000000000000ee20 s __GLOBAL__I_a
0000000000010028 s __GLOBAL__I_a.eh
                 U __Unwind_Resume
0000000000012010 b __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_12_1E
0000000000012011 b __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_12_2E
0000000000012012 b __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_12_3E
0000000000012013 b __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_12_4E
0000000000012014 b __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_12_5E
0000000000012015 b __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_12_6E
0000000000012016 b __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_12_7E
0000000000012017 b __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_12_8E
0000000000012018 b __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_12_9E
000000000000ee60 S __ZN5boost3argILi1EEC1Ev
000000000000fb20 S __ZN5boost3argILi1EEC1Ev.eh
000000000000fa10 S __ZN5boost3argILi1EEC2Ev
0000000000010000 S __ZN5boost3argILi1EEC2Ev.eh
000000000000ee80 S __ZN5boost3argILi2EEC1Ev
000000000000fb70 S __ZN5boost3argILi2EEC1Ev.eh
000000000000fa00 S __ZN5boost3argILi2EEC2Ev
000000000000ffd8 S __ZN5boost3argILi2EEC2Ev.eh
000000000000eea0 S __ZN5boost3argILi3EEC1Ev
000000000000fbc0 S __ZN5boost3argILi3EEC1Ev.eh
000000000000f9f0 S __ZN5boost3argILi3EEC2Ev
000000000000ffb0 S __ZN5boost3argILi3EEC2Ev.eh
000000000000eec0 S __ZN5boost3argILi4EEC1Ev
000000000000fc10 S __ZN5boost3argILi4EEC1Ev.eh
000000000000f9e0 S __ZN5boost3argILi4EEC2Ev
000000000000ff88 S __ZN5boost3argILi4EEC2Ev.eh
000000000000eee0 S __ZN5boost3argILi5EEC1Ev
000000000000fc60 S __ZN5boost3argILi5EEC1Ev.eh
000000000000f9d0 S __ZN5boost3argILi5EEC2Ev
000000000000ff60 S __ZN5boost3argILi5EEC2Ev.eh
000000000000ef00 S __ZN5boost3argILi6EEC1Ev
000000000000fcb0 S __ZN5boost3argILi6EEC1Ev.eh
000000000000f9c0 S __ZN5boost3argILi6EEC2Ev
000000000000ff38 S __ZN5boost3argILi6EEC2Ev.eh
000000000000ef20 S __ZN5boost3argILi7EEC1Ev
000000000000fd00 S __ZN5boost3argILi7EEC1Ev.eh
000000000000f9b0 S __ZN5boost3argILi7EEC2Ev
000000000000ff10 S __ZN5boost3argILi7EEC2Ev.eh
000000000000ef40 S __ZN5boost3argILi8EEC1Ev
000000000000fd50 S __ZN5boost3argILi8EEC1Ev.eh
000000000000f9a0 S __ZN5boost3argILi8EEC2Ev
000000000000fee8 S __ZN5boost3argILi8EEC2Ev.eh
000000000000ef60 S __ZN5boost3argILi9EEC1Ev
000000000000fda0 S __ZN5boost3argILi9EEC1Ev.eh
000000000000f990 S __ZN5boost3argILi9EEC2Ev
000000000000fec0 S __ZN5boost3argILi9EEC2Ev.eh
                 U __ZNKSt3__16locale9use_facetERNS0_2idE
                 U __ZNKSt3__18ios_base6getlocEv
                 U __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEmc
                 U __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED1Ev
                 U __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryC1ERS3_
                 U __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryD1Ev
                 U __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEElsEy
000000000000f460 S __ZNSt3__116__pad_and_outputIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEENS_19ostreambuf_iteratorIT_T0_EES6_PKS4_S8_S8_RNS_8ios_baseES4_
000000000000fe68 S __ZNSt3__116__pad_and_outputIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEENS_19ostreambuf_iteratorIT_T0_EES6_PKS4_S8_S8_RNS_8ios_baseES4_.eh
000000000000f400 S __ZNSt3__13hexERNS_8ios_baseE
000000000000fe40 S __ZNSt3__13hexERNS_8ios_baseE.eh
                 U __ZNSt3__15ctypeIcE2idE
                 U __ZNSt3__16localeD1Ev
                 U __ZNSt3__18ios_base33__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrowEv
                 U __ZNSt3__18ios_base5clearEj
000000000000ef80 S __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc
000000000000fe10 S __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc.eh
                 U __ZSt9terminatev
0000000000000000 T __ZlsRNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERKo
000000000000fdc8 S __ZlsRNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERKo.eh
000000000000f970 S ___clang_call_terminate
000000000000fe98 S ___clang_call_terminate.eh
                 U ___cxa_begin_catch
                 U ___cxa_end_catch
000000000000ed00 s ___cxx_global_var_init
000000000000faf8 s ___cxx_global_var_init.eh
000000000000ed20 s ___cxx_global_var_init1
000000000000fb48 s ___cxx_global_var_init1.eh
000000000000ed40 s ___cxx_global_var_init2
000000000000fb98 s ___cxx_global_var_init2.eh
000000000000ed60 s ___cxx_global_var_init3
000000000000fbe8 s ___cxx_global_var_init3.eh
000000000000ed80 s ___cxx_global_var_init4
000000000000fc38 s ___cxx_global_var_init4.eh
000000000000eda0 s ___cxx_global_var_init5
000000000000fc88 s ___cxx_global_var_init5.eh
000000000000edc0 s ___cxx_global_var_init6
000000000000fcd8 s ___cxx_global_var_init6.eh
000000000000ede0 s ___cxx_global_var_init7
000000000000fd28 s ___cxx_global_var_init7.eh
000000000000ee00 s ___cxx_global_var_init8
000000000000fd78 s ___cxx_global_var_init8.eh
                 U ___gxx_personality_v0
                 U _strlen
```

Comment: are you actually linking with the .a file? its not enough to just create it. or maybe there is a `soStrings.a` already in the library search path. try changing the name to something more unique

Comment: The problems with the presented code do not have anything to do with the linking error. One problem is that `__soStrings__` is a reserved name. Names containing two successive underscores or starting with an underscore followed by uppercase, are reserved to the implementation. Additionally names starting with underscore are reserved in the global namespace. Second problem is design level, including `<iostream>` in a header. Don't, that's a heavy one. Include `<iosfwd>` if you absolutely must. Third problem, for a class meant for reuse it's ungood to be in the global namespace.

Comment: Unix-land linkers such as `ld` are generally pretty sensitive to the order of arguments. I would try some different order.

Comment: Yes, I am creating it, and the static library links fine. I also changed the class name to `soStringsAYE` and the file name to `soStringsFOOBAR.h`, with the same error. The library says it compiles fine. **SOMETHING NEW**: in `main.cpp` if I declare `soStringsAYE myStrings();` I get the warning `Empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration`.

Comment: @senseiwa that's because that is *exactly* what you just did; declare a function. Now show the exact link command, *verbatim*, that you're using to link your lib with your program. While you're at it, also show the *exact* the results of `nm -a libname`, where `libname` is your library.

Comment: @senseiwa: since it's the build that fails it makes sense to omit the information about exact build commands. that way there can be much more fun speculation about it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I am editing right now, you're right. It's a Xcode project, if that matters (clang/libc++).

Comment: Ok, I've added the output of build phases, and `nm` on the library. Also, now I am using `#ifndef QQ__soStrings__` instead of `__soStrings__`.

Comment: There is no void soStrings::insert(const std::string &s) look suspicious

Comment: I yet fail to spot a soStrings.o in the outputs; but there is a soStringsBLAH.o - have you renamed a file and forgotten to tell your build system about it?

Comment: The constructor, destructor, and `insert` methods for `soStringsAYE` are all in `libdummyproj.a` (about eleven items down in the `nm` dump). The *last* line of the `Ld` for your project does *not* appear to contain a linker reference to the actual library. If its there, I can't see it. It doesn't look like your link dependencies are setup right.

Comment: The build files in Xcode for my library are: `file:[...]/soParser.cpp` and `file:[...]/soStringsBLAH.cpp`.

Comment: **SOLVED** Xcode ate my dependency on linking libraries, adding it back solved the problem and now it works. I noticed that Xcode several times gave me something like `Error saving $IDONTREMEMBER, Abort, Retry?`, and I ignored it. *Shame. On. Me. For. Ignoring. Errors.*

Thanks to **ALL** of you for this frustrating session! :)